# Edit a specified cell in a table - jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jsp

I need some help with javascript/jquery or ajax. 
A am writing a java web app and have question regarding table. 
I need to have the possibility to edit one (and only one specified cell). In this case I have the "status" field. When clicking on the value I'd like to have a dropdown list with 2 possibilities to choice: "active" and "passive".

I tried to figure it out, but without success. 
Here is my code:

```
    <body>
    <table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>surname</td>
            <td>status</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Adam</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td id = "status" onclick = "update(this.id)">active</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
function update(id){
var content = document.getElementById(id).firstChild.nodeValue;
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "<input type = 'text' name = 'txtNewInput' id = 'txtNewInput' value = '" + content + "'/>";
  }
    </script>
</body>
```

In this case when I click on the cell the value changes to "null" and it is not editable anymore.

Comment: Why not just make them `<input>`s to begin with?

Comment: Well, I tried to simplify...
The problem is I get the data from a database with java tag:
<td id = "status"><c:out value="${person.status}" /></td>
So I do not want to input anything to a empty field but to update an existing value and save it to the db afterwards.

Comment: As I am not able to edit my post yet, here is the html table I have:
  
<table border = "1">
   <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>surname</td>
    <td>status</td>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach items="${persons}" var="person">
   <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${person.name}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${person.surname}" /></td>
    <td id = "status" onclick = "update(this.id)"><c:out value="${person.status}" /></td>
   </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </table>

The persons is specified in the controller, so there is no declaration in the view

Comment: See my answer. You can put your `<c:out>`s inside HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
<td>
    <input 
      type='text' 
      name='txtNewInput' 
      id='txtNewInput' 
      value='<c:out value="${person.status}" />' 
      onChange='AjaxCallToUpdateDB(this.id, this.value)'
    />
</td>
```

Actually sending the update to the database when the user makes a change requires more than making this an `input`: you need an Ajax call to a Servlet to save the value in the database.

Comment: Not really...
I could do it in this way:
       <td><select id = "selectStatus">
         <option><c:out value="${item.tcStatus}"/></option>
         <option>PASS</option>
         <option>FAIL</option>
       </select></td>

But I want it to be editable after clicking on a specified cell and have only the choosen cell to be editable.